# Serilog property destructuring doesn't work consistently?

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, serilog

I am trying to enrich my Serilog log context with an object and have it's properties show up as destructured in Elasticsearch. This works fine when I am using `LogContext.PushProperty`:

```cs
var conductorContext = new
{
   WorkflowInstanceId,
   task.TaskId,
   TaskName = task.WorkflowTask.Name,
   TaskType,
   task.InputData
};

using (LogContext.PushProperty("ConductorContext", conductorContext, destructureObjects: true))
```

The `ConductorContext` object is neatly destructured and it's properties are individually accessible in Elasticsearch:

```json
"fields" : {
   "ConductorContext" : {
      "WorkflowInstanceId" : "8dca7ebd-4b68-4389-ab98-136bbdf11484",
      "TaskId" : "29cef277-dc33-45a6-8b07-65a4de327f49",
      "TaskName" : "LoadAangrijpOmsDataTask",
      "TaskType" : "LoadAangrijpOmsDataTask",
      "InputData" : null
   }
}
```

However, when I use `WithProperty` (I want to add a global object) as follows (in my `Program.cs:Main` method:

```cs
Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
   .Enrich.WithProperty("NomadContext", new
   {
      AllocationId = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("NOMAD_ALLOC_ID"),
      AllocationName = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("NOMAD_ALLOC_NAME"),
      JobId = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("NOMAD_JOB_ID"),
      JobName = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("NOMAD_JOB_NAME"),
      GroupName = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("NOMAD_GROUP_NAME"),
      TaskName = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("NOMAD_TASK_NAME")
   }, destructureObjects: true)
```

The `NomadContext` shows up as a string in Elasticsearch:

```json
"fields" : {
   "NomadContext" : "{ AllocationId = 293dd620-955c-7f8d-b6b5-9a36546bd29d, AllocationName = da_pub_worker.group_da_pub_worker[1], JobId = , JobName = da_pub_worker, GroupName = group_da_pub_worker, TaskName = task_da_pub_worker }"
}
```

I cannot figure out why the first works and the latter doesn't. What am I missing?

I am using the Serilog.Sinks.Elasticsearch package.

Comment: When an object in the Net Library have multiple parents links to the object the object is not disposed until all the links are broken.  When in a using block an object is automatically disposed when exiting the block.  So it looks like your case is the 2nd case.  So you must put the call to the LoggerConfiguration() method inside a using block for it to get disposed.

Comment: @jdweng Thanks, but I'm not sure how your comment is relevant. I am not looking for the object to be disposed. Functionally, logging is working but my issue is that the NomadContext is not detructured properly. I'll update my question to show how the LoggerConfiguration is used.

Comment: The reason the first method is disposing is the code is inside a using block.   As I said anything inside the using block gets disposed when exiting the block.  the 2nd method does not have a using block so it is not getting disposed.

Comment: Hi Erik - I tested this, and `NomadContext` comes out as structured data for me (with `WriteTo.Console(new JsonFormatter())` ) - which sink are you using/how are you determining the format of the output?

Comment: Hi @NicholasBlumhardt my apologies. I'm using Elasticsearch and the Serilog.Sinks.Elasticsearch package. Obviously, the problem could easily be in the latter. I've added the extra information to my question.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was not in Serilog or in the Serilog.Sinks.Elasticsearch package, but in the configuration of my ELK stack itself.

Deleting and re-creating my indices made the NomadContext come up properly destructured.